# How to write AssemblyVersion to file using MSBuild?

Tags: version-control, msbuild, doxygen

FinalEdit: Despite relative directories not working in the first post, it worked if I simply removed the `$(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)` from the `Exec` line.

Edit2: I added the new targets to the `DefaultTargets`. Which now runs them by default. However, timing was now off with the postbuild command. I added `<Exec Command="call $(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)documentation\tools\GenerateDocumentation.bat" IgnoreExitCode="false" />` to the target, but it gives an error that `C:\Users\my` is not a valid batch file because of the space which is actually `C:\Users\my program\documentation\tools\GenerateDocumentation.bat`. Putting quotes around the path gives me error `MSB4025` that Name cannot begin with `$`.

Edit: I have tried stijn's code and it works when I explicitly run it from the command line using /t:RetrieveIdentities, but for some reason it doesn't seem to run otherwise.

I have been using Doxygen to generate documentation for my source code, however, I would like to be able to do it automatically. I wrote a simple `.bat` script to run Doxygen with my desired config file and compile the output into a `.chm` help file, but I have been unable to change the revision number automatically in Doxygen.

I was attempting to simply update the config file by adding a new line to the config file with the new revision number using MSBuild, but I have been unable to get anything to print or even create a new file when none is present.

The code I have so far I have gotten from other similar questions, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyTextFile Include="\documentation\DoxygenConfigFile.doxyconfig"/>
  <MyItems Include="PROJECT_NUMBER         = %(MyAssemblyIdentitiesAssemblyInfo.Version)"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="RetrieveIdentities">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="bin\foo.exe">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <WriteLinesToFile File="@(MyTextFile)" Lines="@(MyItems)" Overwrite="false" Encoding="UTF8" />
</Target>
```

Comment: In the future make your question include the msbuild output/errors etc, just saying "it does not work" is unclear. Also ideally one should be able to just copy/paste the script code you post, run it, and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Encoding` is wrong, it should be `UTF-8`
2. When working with items/properties, the `%` and `@` and `$` must come right before the `(`, no spacing in between: `%(MyAssemblyIdentitiesAssemblyInfo.Version)`
3. `MyAssemblyIdentitiesAssemblyInfo` does not exist, you probably meant `MyAssemblyIdentities`
4. Look up how msbuild evaluates properties and items. Basically what it will do in your script is evaluate `MyItems`, but at that time `MyAssemblyIdentities` does not yet exist so is empty, and only afterwards the `GetAssemblyIdentity` gets executed. Fix this by enforcing correct evaluation order: put your items inside the target and make it depend on another target that creates `MyAssemblyIdentities` before evaluating your items.

To summarize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<Target Name="GetAssemblyIdentities">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="bin\foo.exe">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
</Target>

<Target Name="RetrieveIdentities" DependsOnTargets="GetAssemblyIdentities">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyTextFile Include="\documentation\DoxygenConfigFile.doxyconfig"/>
    <MyItems Include="PROJECT_NUMBER = %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <WriteLinesToFile File="@(MyTextFile)" Lines="@(MyItems)"
                    Overwrite="false" Encoding="UTF-8" />
</Target>

</Project>
```

Note this will only work if you invoke msbuild in the directory where the script is, else the paths (documentation/foo) will be wrong. That could be fixed by using eg `$(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)\bin\foo.exe`)

Comment: 1. I tried that originally, didn't seem to make a difference.
2. Sorry about that, I must have messed up the paste, it is correct in the code.
3. I completely missed that.

For some reason it is still not printing to the file. When I change the name of the file in the directory, MSBuild throws an error that it is not found, otherwise no errors are found and nothing is printed to the file. 

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Without the correct encoding the error message is `error MSB3098: "WriteLinesToFile" task received an invalid value for the "Encoding" parameter`?? Anyway I tested the above on my system and it works as expected, so if it down't work for you'll have to provide more information. Please update your question stating exactly what you tried, and what the output was. Also if things don't work in msbuild, use `<Message Text="..."/>` to show the values of properties/items as a debugging aid.

Comment: I finally figured out how to get the `Exec` command to work. Do you know why I couldn't use relative paths in my original example but had to use it for the `Command`? 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: probably has something to do with `Exex` starting a seperate process. You can always start a new question with that specific question.